# How can you counter Orianna?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am maining midlane and have trouble with Orianna.

I've played different champions against her with mixed success.

- **Karthus** is quite good against Orianna if I dodge her poke and just farm from range with q, but well yes, he's always a safe pick.
- I've tried **different AD Mages** including Jayce, Trynd, Panth, and Talon against her and all seemed to work out pretty well but mainly because Orianna went MR.

How else can you counter Orianna?

Comment: Hi, Christoffer.  I am voting to close your question as it's too broad; we could have a separate answer for each and every champion.  From the answers, it seems that Orianna is very skill-shot heavy.  Maybe asking "How can I counter skill shots" would get you some good answers.

Comment: As fbueckert said, rather than requesting a list of champions, detail the specific strategies and problems you are having when facing Orianna. The more detail you add, the more likely you will get a good answer that can help you!

Answer (score 6):

**Orianna is very reliant on her ball, pick champions with high mobility and/or sustain. When playing against Orianna, take consideration of these points.**

1. *Always* stay away from the ball, if you run into the ball she'll cast her spells on it. Try to dodge it too. (start with boots)
2. *If* she planted the ball near you, try to have minions between you and the ball, it reduces the damage per target hit.
3. *Orianna's* spell damage is not super high early game because of that she will try to harrass you despite her mana cost on her q being lowered a month ago or so. She will run out of mana quickly.
4. *Orianna* is very squishy, try to harrass her back, after she missed a q. you can bully her around for a few sec.
5. *As* i've mentioned before, Orianna can't instantly kill you, she counts on harrassing you to 50% health before actully attemping to attack(thats early and middle game) so if you are willing to have a clash with her, make it fast.
6. *Orianna* has such short cooldowns with the right items, not to mention that she counts on the combo of her skills all together so any silence or stun in the middle of her combo will ruin it.
7. *Beware* of her passive, it gets underestimated a lot but when she gets a few autoattacks on you, it hurts..

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro you confused the everliving crap out of me, as i clicked edit to remove the same line of text you did, it dissapeared. apparently great minds think alike. at the same time.

Comment: @Ender: Hudda hudda... oh, wrong game. I meant, "*indeed!*"

Answer (score 1):

Champions that can move are really good at getting away from where the ball is flying. Along with champions that tend to buy early MR. Kennen is an example and countered me today. He was able to dodge my ball and bought a early Negatron cloak to negate a lot of my damage. Easily building his negatron into an abyssal scepter. Galio counters most AP's due to his passive and that is still true here. Highly tanky and normally builds MR will shut down Orianna's damage overall. Hopefully this helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Orianna is extremely reliant on her skill shots, with hitting them she's worthless. So, if you can bait her skillshots you can harass her down, her cooldowns and mana will catch up to her so you should be able to win the lane. Try out some MS Quints on your mid champions, a lot of people won't see it coming, and you'll have enough mobility in lane to keep away from harass.